# Unifying various HTTP request tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms

There are [httprequest](/questions/tagged/httprequest), [http-request](/questions/tagged/http-request) and [http-requests](/questions/tagged/http-requests) tags. These should be unified into one, preferably [http-request](/questions/tagged/http-request).

If we choose [http-request](/questions/tagged/http-request) then current [httpresponse](/questions/tagged/httpresponse) should be changed to [http-response](/questions/tagged/http-response) as well.

Comment: I don't think that is a dumb restriction at all.  With less than 5 upvotes in a certain tag how can we tell if the user knows enough about the topic? I got most my rep in the ****book tag, but I'm definitely not the right person to suggest synonyms for C# or Python...

Comment: @Lix What knowledge does it take to know `httprequest` and `http-request` refer to the same? Although I have several answers on questions about http requests I don't have score 5 or more because these questions are tagged with other tags :)

Comment: Changed this to a pure support request.  As a feature request, the business of keeping the site in order (as best we can) will get lost.  The requirements aren't going to change, at least, not by any argument put forth in this post.  If you want to post that the requirements be lessened for Stack Overflow, I'd recommend a separate feature request (although they're high on Stack Overflow because of the insane traffic).

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: None, **in this case**. But the tag synonym system really isn't meant to handle silly things like this. Creating alternate tags that differ by only a dash or an "s" is now forbidden, so it's just a matter of cleaning up all the ones that were already created. A *normal* synonym suggestion would require more expertise than "oh there's just a dash in this one."

Comment: @pio, I was only referring to your comments on the restriction.. Sure there are gonna be some obvious cases, but the system needs to accommodate for all cases. Synonym suggestions are not always as straight forward as the ones in your post.

Comment: Please stop directly pinging moderators or bumping your posts like this. If you want to bump a post without a meaningful edit, place a bounty.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Did you delete my comment here?

Comment: No, another moderator did.